# Why is this nvd3 chart not resizing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, nvd3.js

I've created a population pyramid in nvd3, but it's not resizing as it's supposed to, and I cannot diagnose why. Here's a pen with the problematic code: http://codepen.io/laissezpasser/pen/qNrPXQ

For comparison, here's a working example of the responsiveness I'm trying to achieve in the pen above: Try [resizing one of the windowpanes in this pen: http://codepen.io/laissezpasser/pen/jrBGQG

For some reason, it seems to be ignoring the following code:

```
nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
return chart;
```

Comment: Works for me...in Chrome

Comment: The first link doesn't automatically resize for me in either Chrome Version 52.0.2743.49 beta (64-bit) or Firefox 47, both running on OSX 10.11.6 Beta.

Comment: Then I guess it's an OSX thing. I'm on Windoze.

Comment: I just realized the first link in the OP directs to the wrong pen. Try http://codepen.io/laissezpasser/pen/qNrPXQ (And if a moderator is able to edit my OP, I'd be most grateful.)